# I change the renderer with one click and then directly query an item (ref). SetTimeout a good solution?

Tags: reactjs

**I change the renderer with one click and then directly query an item (ref). setTimeout a good solution?**
*(I don't know if I change the renderer in a single click, then in the event I can do anything in the fresh renderer. setTimeout good solution? Someone else has a different solution because I feel like I didn't do it well.)*

```
import React from 'react';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            con1: false,
            con2: false
        };
    }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    parseFloat(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-id')) === 1 ? 
    (this.setState({
        con1: true,
        con2: false
    })) 
    : 
    (this.setState({
        con2: true,
        con1: false
    }));


    /* Good, but this is valid???  */
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(this.buttonContainer.childNodes[0])
    },0)


   /* Not good
   console.log(this.buttonContainer.childNodes[0]);
   */
  }

  render() {
    const { con1, con2 } = this.state;

        return (
        <div className="app-container">
            <button
                data-id="1"
                onClick = {(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                >
                Button
            </button>
            <button
                data-id="2"
                onClick = {(e) => this.handleClick(e)}
                >
                Button
            </button>

            <div
                className="button-conteiner"
                ref={(ref) => this.buttonContainer = ref}
            >

            { con1 ? 
                (<div className="container1">container1</div>)
                :
                (null)
            }

            { con2 ? 
                (<div className="container2">container2</div>)
                :
                (null)
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use useEffect hook with function components in this case. the logic will be more readable

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Test = props => {
  const [con1, setCon1] = useState(false);
  const [con2, setCon2] = useState(false);
  const buttonContainer = useRef(null);
  const handleClick = e => {
    const b = parseFloat(e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id")) === 1;
    setCon1(b);
    setCon2(!b);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if(buttonContainer.current) {
      console.log(buttonContainer.current.childNodes[0])
    }
  }, [buttonContainer.current, con1, con2])

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <button data-id="1" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}>
        Button
      </button>
      <button data-id="2" onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}>
        Button
      </button>

      <div
        className="button-conteiner"
        ref={buttonContainer}
      >
        {con1 ? <div className="container1">container1</div> : null}

        {con2 ? <div className="container2">container2</div> : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```